# Receiving BLE broadcast (ADV_NONCONN_IND) packets in Android SDK

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to capture BLE broadcast (ADV_NONCONN_IND) packets inside of my android app. However I'm not able to receive any packets.

I know my peripheral device is sending packets because I have another BLE capture device that sees all the packets. However my app inside the phone doesn't see any BLE packets.

My app can see other packets such as ADV_SCAN_ID but not ADV_NONCONN_IND (broadcast) packets.

```
public void uploadScanBytes(SensorDataUploader sensorDataUploader, int count) {
        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = getBluetoothAdapter();
        if (btAdapter == null) return;

        BluetoothLeScanner scanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
                .build();
        scanner.startScan(Collections.<ScanFilter>emptyList(), settings, new LimitedScanRecordReader(sensorDataUploader, count, scanner));
    }


public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {

   if(result.getDevice().getAddress().equals("00:AB:2c:A1:E2:F1")) {
       long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() -   SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
                        result.getTimestampNanos() / 1000000;
                byte[] rawBytes = result.getScanRecord().getBytes();
                Log.i(DataTransferService.class.getName(), "Raw bytes: " + byteArrayToHex(rawBytes));
                sensorDataUploader.upload(timestamp, rawBytes);
            }
}
```

Please let me know what I'm missing.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you solve this problem?